# How Open new tab in chrome using php

Tags: javascript, php, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am getting a Link from a website using selenium and i have to goto these links and extract some other Info and return back and insert all the info in db.
So I need help to open new tab instead of opening a new window so i can save all the values without loosing any data.

Comment: That isn't something PHP should do, this seems like a Javascript problem

Comment: Hi, Could you please add your selenium code and describe what is the behavior and what it should be ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Javascript executor ,you could something like this :

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open('"+url+"','_blank');");
```

here URL is a variable, you can use your own URL.